# Copying HttpServletRequest of one client to bodyof HttpServletResponse of another client

Tags: java, servlets, http-request

I need to copy the `HttpServletRequest` of client1, as it is, to the `HttpServletResponse` object created for client2. According to [this](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/http/reference/httprequest.html) `HttpRequest` has a ResuestLine, then headers, then body. 
I have copied the headers like this :

```
 Enumeration<?> headerNames = client1Req.getHeaderNames();
    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String headerName = (String) headerNames.nextElement();

        Enumeration<?> headers = client1Req.getHeaders(headerName);
        while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
            String headerValue = (String) headers.nextElement();
            responseToClient2.addHeader(headerName, headerValue);
            responseToClient2.setHeader(headerName, headerValue);
            System.out.println("headername : "  + headerName + "value : " + headerValue);
        }
```

and body like this:

```
input = clientReq.getInputStream();
        output = responseToRIC.getOutputStream();
        if((len=input.available()) > 0){
            len = input.read(outputByte);
            System.out.println("len : "+len);
            output.write(outputByte);
            output.flush();
        }   
        else{
            System.out.println("no body");
        }
```

However, i need to copy the request line too. If i try to read the input stream instead in the beginning instead of reading headers and body separately, it return -1.
There is no api for reading the entire request line from an `HttpServletRequest`. If I read the URL using `getRequestURL()` and `getQuesrystring()`, where should I place it in the responseToClient2?
In a custom header `REQUESTLINE` or should i write it on the outputstream?
Thanks

EDIT : since it is semantically wrong to copy a `request` to a `response`, i have decided to copy the `request` tothe payload or body of the `response`. However, since the `HttpServletRequest` is not serializable, i am unable to write it on the `outputstream` of `response`, any suggestions as to how I should achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do here. Request and response have different purposes and different specs so what is your real requirement? To just copy one to the other seems wrong.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. A valid request is not a valid response in HTTP.

Comment: Client2 is behind a firewall which blocks incoming requests but allows outgoing requests. I have to relay client1's request to an appserver on client2's side. Client1 cannot directly send a request to the appserver because of the firewall. Hence, I have placed my own server outside the firewall and client1 sends requests for the appserver to my server. My server also receives requests from Client2 and responds to it with the request of client1. I agree that requests and responses have totally different purposes. But then how do I achieve what i want to?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to write some sort of proxy?